# How to read ib_logfile0?

Tags: mysql

I have received ib_logfile0 file.

Now I want to read the file. How can I do the same?

Main motive behind this is somehow I need to understand the schema for the list of tables that ib_logfile0 is tagged to. Is it worth putting efforts reading this file for the purpose mentioned.

Thanks for your time.

Thanks and Regards,

SachinJadhav.

Answer (score 0):

`ib_logfile0` is a [redo log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_INNODB_REDO_LOG.html) used for crash recovery. It contains a log of commited transactions that haven't been applied to the tablespaces.

It is important to keep this file, its not some throw away item and its contents a vitally important to the operation of innodb.

The contents aren't simple, and due to the abstraction probably not worth spending time on. In addition to the official docs, [Jeremy Cole did a blog series](https://blog.jcole.us/innodb/), possibly a bit dated now, and [set of tools to read files](https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_ruby). Failing that there is always the source code.

Answer (score -1):

The following command will give you a list of table names and some garbage too, but you should be able to recognize the table names it applies to.

```
strings ib_logfile0
```